# Android Declaring Variables before OnCreate?

Tags: android, variables, scope, textwatcher

Is it possible to create variables before the `onCreate()` method in Android? I have tried doing so in the past but to no avail so I'm assuming you cant, but I just want to double check. The reason why is because I am trying to access a variable in my `TextWatcher` that serves as a counter, but its out of scope and asking for me to make it final, which obviously doesnt work since its serving as a counter and is needed to increment. I have attached my code below:

```
int counter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordtoanswer);
     final ArrayList updatedList = helperMethod();
     text.setText(updatedList.get(0).toString());
     final String wordFinal = updatedList.get(0).toString();

     while(true)
     {
    answerText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            System.out.println(counter);
            String answer = s.toString();
            if(answer.equals(wordFinal))
            {   
                text.setText(updatedList.get(counter).toString());
                answerText.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
    counter++;
}
}
```

Hopefully you guys understand why I'm trying to declare it before the `onCreate()`, because only then can the methods inside the `TextWatcher` actually access it without them being out of scope. Is there anyway I can get around this problem? Please let me know if you need more information/code!

Comment: Would changing it to be int counter before the on create and then intializing it to 0 in the OnCreate method make it work? I'm trying to test it out but am having issues connecting android phone to eclipse!

Answer (score 2):

Declare the reference as a member variable:

```
private TextView text;
```

Instantiate it in OnCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordtoanswer);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Great thats what I figured I ought to try. I remember declaring variables outside the OnCreate methods in the past, I guess I forgot that I cannot initialize them outside the OnCreate method.

Comment: You can't intialize anything that needs a `Context` before `onCreate()`. But other `Object`s you can

Comment: Hmm okay well I'll try doing what valbertos suggested and just initializing the variable inside the onCreate method!

Comment: Try it and let me know ;)